# Name and password individual check in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I am writing a deliberately vulnerable web application. I'd like to figure out how to check username and password, matching against the database and each other as well.

So: if the username exists in the database and the password exists in the database and the username and password belongs together. I'm fully aware how to send a query which checks for both at the same time and returns either true or false, so please don't start on that. My goal is to individually check for both so I can inform the user which one is not working.

Here's my code but as I'm not really a PHP person this is obviously not working:

```
<?php 
if(isset($_POST["submit"])){
    $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['username']);
    $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['password']); 

    $sql_username = "SELECT id FROM users WHERE username = '$username'";
    $sql_password = "SELECT id FROM users WHERE password = '$password'";
    $result_username = mysqli_query($conn, $sql_username);
    $result_password = mysqli_query($conn, $sql_password);
    $row_username = mysqli_fetch_array($result_username);
    $row_password = mysqli_fetch_array($result_password);
    $count_username = mysqli_num_rows($result_username);
    $count_password = mysqli_num_rows($result_password);

    if($count_username > 0 && $count_password < 0) {
        echo "Invalied password";
    } else if ($count_username < 0 && $count_password > 0) {
        echo "Invalied username";
    } else {
        "Welcome";
    }
}
?>
```

Any hints?

### Edit

$conn can be used as I'm getting it from another php file.

Comment: **WARNING**: Writing your own access control layer is not easy and there are many opportunities to get it severely wrong. Please, do not write your own authentication system when any modern [development framework](http://codegeekz.com/best-php-frameworks-for-developers/) like [Laravel](http://laravel.com/) comes with a robust [authentication system](https://laravel.com/docs/master/authentication) built-in. At the absolute least follow [recommended security best practices](http://www.phptherightway.com/#security) and **never store passwords as plain-text** or a weak hash like **SHA1 or MD5**.

Comment: Note: The object-oriented interface to `mysqli` is significantly less verbose, making code easier to read and audit, and is not easily confused with the obsolete `mysql_query` interface. Before you get too invested in the procedural style it’s worth switching over. Example: `$db = new mysqli(…)` and `$db->prepare("…")` The procedural interface is an artifact from the PHP 4 era when `mysqli` API was introduced and should not be used in new code.

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST`, `$_GET` or **any** user data directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Comment: You **never** check the password in the database because if you can do a plain-text match you're already in trouble. A good password hashing algorithm produces essentially random output, but it can be verified if and *only if* you have the correct "guess". The proper procedure is to find the matching user row, load in that data, and verify the hash using `password_verify`.

Comment: dear Tadman, thank you very much for your ideas. please ignore all security flaws in my code and focus on the question. believe or not, my absolute purpose is to make the app as vulnerable as that is possible - hence the verbose user information about the username and password to. thank you.

Comment: This code will let you in if I type in "admin" which is a user and "pass123" which is a password for *anyone*. This does not check that the admin user's password is correct.

Comment: None of this code makes any sense. Why not just let them in without even trying if that's the goal? This isn't how real-world login code is structured, so I'm not sure what you're trying to prove, even from an academic perspective. If you could better explain that part we could probably address that specifically.

Comment: that's unfortunately wrong, this code gives zero reaction to any kind of input. i assume it cannot send more than 1 query on one button press.

Comment: This runs two queries per request. Not sure where you're going with this. If you have one row with "admin" as a username and another, completely unrelated row with "pass123" as the password then guessing that combination will allow entry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    <?php
    //set up a connection and all that prerequisite stuff
    $sqlConnectionNameHere = new mysqli($sql_host, $sql_username, $sql_password, $sql_dbname);
    $username = 'bob'; //the username that will be checked
    $password = 'securepassword1'; //the password that will be checked
    $query = $sqlConnectionNameHere->query("SELECT username, password FROM users WHERE username='$username' LIMIT 1"); //make your query

    if ($query->num_rows != 1){ //if the datbase didn't return any rows, the user with $username must not exist
        die('User not found!');
    }

    while ($user = $query->fetch_assoc()){
        if ($user['password'] != $password){
            die('Invalid Password');
        }
    }

    //if they've made it here, the user exists and the password matches!

    echo 'Welcome!';
?>
```

This is a really barebones way of doing it. You may want to add more security to this.

Hope this helps. Best of luck to you!

Comment: I know you're just trying to help, but these quick solutions create more problems than they solve.

Comment: 1. this example is invalid, because it re-uses `$username` variable for connection and for user's check 2. this example introduces SQL injection

Answer (score 0):

I know its way cooler to let the user know wether the username or password is wrong. But this actually helps get unwanted indivuduals to pass this test. Since they can test if a specific user is present or not. From there this individual would bruteforce the password. So its a good practice to just check for username AND password.

Furthermore you can store the password as a hash. This way not even the hoster of your db has a direct access to the passwords. Use [MD5](http://php.net/manual/de/function.md5.php) or [SHA](http://php.net/manual/de/function.sha1.php). As example the credentials in your db would look like:

```
User       Password
Admin      098f6bcd4621d373cade4e832627b4f6
```

This is a MD5 hash. You'll get this hash if you process `md5('test')`. A hash is a **one way** "encryption" function. You check it by hashing the user-input and comparing this result with the stored hash.

If you check for this password you'd bind it like this:

`$stmt->bind_param("ss", $_POST['username'], md5($_POST['password']));`

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "my_db");
```

**Plaintext password(not recommended!) - prepared select**

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT id FROM users WHERE username=? AND password=?");

// type string, string ("ss")
$stmt->bind_param("ss", $_POST['username'], $_POST['password']);

// hashed (recommended)
// $stmt->bind_param("ss", $_POST['username'], md5($_POST['password']));

$stmt->execute();

// set target for the id-column
$stmt->bind_result($id);

// Will be TRUE if a row has been found
if( $stmt->fetch() ) {
    echo "Welcome! user:{$id}";
} else {
    echo "Invalid username or password";
}
```

For details have a look at [mysqli prepare](http://php.net/manual/de/mysqli.prepare.php)
And a little more security related: [Password hashing](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Password_Storage_Cheat_Sheet#Password_hashing_usage)

Comment: I appreciate your concern and help Pilan, but in fact the reason for this code is to present vulnerabilities. :) Thanks for your contribution though!

Comment: oh :( - well this code is public now and will get copy pasted - i can sleep better when i know there is an answer in here that points it out

Comment: sleep well mate :)